# Switching power supply conversion 110 in 220

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I have a switching power dedicated to the use of devices with a cigarette lighter plug in the 110 V sector, and I want to convert it for the 220V sector. I attached the diagram. I will replace the capacitors C9 and C1 with 400V and add a resistor of 1M ohm in series with R2. I ask your help in confirming this change.
It is designed to run the "Camping cooler" that use a peltier thermoelectric cooler, [TEC1-12706](https://peltiermodules.com/peltier.datasheet/TEC1-12706.pdf)

Note :
following the remark of Mr TimWescott, Hearth and Tony Stewart EE75, I modified the diagram for more clarity

[image]

Comment: I don't recommend using this power supply on either 110 *or* 220 volts input; there's no feedback to keep the output regulated, and I'd worry about how hot that K2141 might get (though my worry might be unfounded, it just has much too high an Rdson for my taste). And on 220 volt input, the 400 volt capacitors seem like not enough margin for me.

Comment: The biggest problem is typically the transformer, which does not come with a datasheet, but needs to be rated for the higher voltage. The higher voltage is also going to drive up the frequency by pushing current faster into the transformer, the switching losses could go up with the frequency

Comment: It is designed to run the "Camping cooler" that use a peltier thermoelectric cooler, so there is no need to get feedback

Comment: @Hearth  . This is typical primary side feedback with tertiary windings

Comment: Yes the critical part is the core tertiary turns ratio and inductance as well as orientation. Overvoltage insulation is more obvious.  Impedance and energy transfer changes from 120V to 240V are primary concern so as not to introduce a new problem. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ssb7g.png,

Comment: We get a lot automobiles that get exported from 120V cities to 240V cities for 5 finger discounts. Was this how you got yours?  I see a picture of a 12V load but not the 120Vac supply

Comment: To be sure that it's going to work, _every single part_ on the high-voltage side needs to be reviewed and possibly replaced.  As mentioned, this sort of thing depends on a lot of details of the transformer behavior, and you don't have access to that.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 When you have a third winding on the transformer, you need to show that the third winding is actually on the transformer core. There was an inductor that I was a little confused by, but no indication whatsoever that it shared a core with any other winding; it looks like the question has since been edited to show that.

Comment: Yes, I already knew that so I was just informing you of that because they don't work without some form of feedback  FWIW @Hearth  (contrary to what @ maher believes

Answer (score 1):

The conversion between 220VAC and 110VAC will be technically harder than the conversion down to 12VDC from either voltage.

So, the easiest, cheapest, safest and most compact solution is to simply get a 12 V switch-mode supply for the grid voltage you're planning to use. These are cheap, and honestly, architecturally better than what you seem to have already. In fact, properly regulated 12V 5A supplies can be had as trash - in the shape of PC power supplies, printer power supplies, and a lot of other things. Second-hand/auction sites are a possible source, but so are tme.eu, pollin.de, reichelt.de or farnell.com.

Comment: Yes, yes, but this modification is for educational purposes

Comment: I have a solution but I do not know if it is functional or not, instead of modifying the assembly I would add a triac-based voltage drop and a bridge diode, see the link :
https://imgur.com/a/msYChNa